# Solr 3.5 not indexing

Tags: solr

The problem I'm having is that Solr isn't indexing and I'm not getting any exceptions in the log files.  I'm using Tomcat 7 server and am connecting to a MS Server.  My data-config.xml is as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<dataConfig>
  <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource"
       driver="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
       url="jdbc:sqlserver://testserver:2120;databaseName=testdb"
       user="test"
       password="test1" />
  <document name="parts">
    <entity name="id"
       query="select distinct pa.part_id, pa.part_number, pa.part_description, pa.usage_text, pa.quantity, d.make, d.model, d.model_qualifier_id, @category, @subcategory from testdb..part_application_v pa inner join testdb..equipment_detailed_v d on pa.make = d.make and pa.model inner join testdb..page_part_application ppa on ppa.application_id = pa.application_id where ppa.page_id in (select p.page_id from testdb..page p inner join testdb..nav_lang nl on nl.nav_desc_id = p.nav_desc_id inner join testdb..page_chapter_xref pcx on p.pageId = pcx.page_id and chapter_id in (select deistinct chapter_id from testdb.dbo.chapter_v where parent_id in (select distinct chapter_id from testdb.dbo.chapters_v where catalog_id in (select ed.catalog_id from testdb.models_v m inner join testdb..equipment_detailed_v ed on ed.make_id = (select distinct make_id from testdb..equipment_detailed_v where make = @make) and ed.model_qualifier_id = @year and m.model_id = ed.model_id where m.model_id = (select distinct model_id from testdb..equipment_detailed_v where model = @model)) and parent_id is null and name = @category) and name = @subcategory) inner join testdb..chapters_v c on pcx.chapter_id = c.chapter_id and p.image_id is not null and testdb.dbo.utility_fn_filtermatch(null,p.filter_equation) = 1) and testdb.dbo.utility_fn_filtermatch(null,pa.filter-equation) = 1 and d.model_qualifier_id = @year order by ppa.page_id, pa.part_description />
    <field column="pa.part_id" name="partId" />
    <field column="pa.part_number" name="partNumber" />
    <field column="pa.part_description" name="desc" />
    <field column="pa.usage_text" name="usage" />
    <field column="pa.quantity" name="qty" />
    <field column="d.make" name="make" />
    <field column="d.model" name="model" />
    <field column="d.model_qualifier_id" name="year" />
    <field column="@category" name="category" />
    <field column="@subcategory" name="subcategory" />
  </document>
</dataConfig>
```

With out some sort of error being thrown, I'm not even sure where to begin debugging this.  I would be very thankful for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things.

First, your entity element is an empty tag with no field elements inside. Instead of closing it with "/>", close it with ">" and add "" after all the field elements. Yes, the DataImportHandler probably should give an error when there is a field element not inside an entity element.

Second, newlines are legal inside an attribute, so you do not have to put that query all on one line. Wow, that is hard to read. You can do it like this:

```
<entity name="id"
        query="select
               table.name as name,
               table.id as id
               from table">
  <field column="name"/>
  <field column="id"/>
</entity>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll make those changes and post back how it goes.